# How to merge arrays within while loop inside single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code.

```
$w = array();
while ($rowData = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {  
                                                $w[] = $rowData ;
                                            } 
print_r($w) ;
```

$w gives me following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Sumit Manager
            [role_id] => 2
            [punch_in] => 2015-11-06 06:27:29
            [id] => 1042
            [punch_out] => 2015-11-06 06:28:38
            [working_hours] => 00:01:09
            [hourlyrate] => 20.0000
            [payable] => 0.38333332
            [time_status] => out_time
            [user_id] => 77
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Sumit Manager
            [role_id] => 2
            [punch_in] => 2015-11-06 06:28:38
            [id] => 1044
            [punch_out] => 2015-11-06 06:29:15
            [working_hours] => 00:00:37
            [hourlyrate] => 20.0000
            [payable] => 0.20555554
            [time_status] => out_break
            [user_id] => 77
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => John Server
            [role_id] => 3
            [punch_in] => 2015-11-06 06:28:17
            [id] => 1043
            [punch_out] => 2015-11-06 06:29:56
            [working_hours] => 00:01:39
            [hourlyrate] => 12.0000
            [payable] => 0.33000000
            [time_status] => out_time
            [user_id] => 78
        )

)
```

What I want is to merge above arrays within loop into single array with indexes like below.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array (array1 from loop),
        [1] => Array (array2 from loop)
    )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, isn't the array all ready like you want it?

Comment: `$w` gives 2 arrays as output? how? What is producing `Sumit Manager` and what is producing `John Server` ?

Comment: What happens when you use `print_r($w) ;exit;`? Please give what exactly `$w` produces. Is while loop in a loop itself already?

Comment: Yes there is a for loop outside while loop from where I pass user id and and while loop gives data for those users.

Comment: provide you full code with the while loop in the for loop. You can also provide the demo for the same . So that your question is better understood and better answered

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x = [];
for(){ // Your for loop here
    $w = array();
    while ($rowData = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {  
        $w[] = $rowData; // create a array for current Id rows
    } 
    $x = array_merge($x, $w); // Merge the array generated to the for lopping array.
}
print_r($x);
```

Here when the for loop starts it will trigger a while loop which will store all the rows generated by while loop inside `$w` array. After that it will be pushed to the outer loop array `$x`.

**SOLUTION 2**

You can simply use `$x[] = $w;` instead of `$x = array_merge($x, $w);`.

Answer (score -1):

`array_merge` will be useful here.

```
$w = array();
while ($rowData = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {  
    $w = array_merge($w, $rowData) ;
} 

print_r($w) ;
```

`$w = array();` should be outside `for` loop.

Comment: This is not a solution as expected  as it will give a single array having all the while and for loop rows inside one single array.

Comment: The requirement is merging into a single array. Please don't down vote until OP confirms it.